# Erro ao criar Modulo zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Criei um módulo novo no zend, porem ele dá como erro 404.

**modules.config.php**

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Album' <-- módulo que foi criado.
];
```

**module.config.php**

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\AlbumController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file:
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Module.php**

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const VERSION = '3.0.3-dev';

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

**AlbumController**

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**Estrutura das pastas:**

```
-Album
   -config
       -module.config.php
   -src
       -Controller
           -AlbumController.php
       -Module.php
   -view
       -album
           -album
               -index.phtml
       -error
       -layout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!
Qual a versão do Zend Framework você está utilizando? se for acima da 3.0, você precisa, além dos passos que você utilizou, criar a entrada para seu novo módulo também no arquivo composer.json e rodar um dump-autoload.

Isso se deve ao fato que o Zend Framework 3 obedece ao [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), ou seja, o autoload das classes é todo tratado pelo composer.

Seu Composer.json deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
{
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Common\\": "module/Common/src/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"
    }
},
...
}
```

Lembre-se de rodar o composer dump-autoload no terminal depois de alterar o arquivo.
[Aqui](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/PHP_Class_Autoloading.html) tem uma boa documentação sobre o autoloader do ZF3.

**Edit:**

Complementando a resposta com os itens discutidos nos comentários abaixo:
Primeiramente no modules.config.php, inclui o namespace completo do controller, ficando assim:

```
<?php use Zend\Router\Http\Segment; use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            \Album\Controller\AlbumController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file:
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'album' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => \Album\Controller\AlbumController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ], ];
```

Depois no controller, corrigi o retorno do método indexAction para que o mesmo retorne uma instância do objeto ViewModel

```
<?php
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Conforme comentei abaixo, testei em um projeto novo aqui e tudo funcionou corretamente, seguindo as etapas descritas nos comentários.

Veja se com isso resolve por ai.

**Edit 2:**

Bom, vamos a mais um edit, uma coisa que notei em seu projeto no git é que você usou a estrutura de diretórios do zend 2, no zend 3 ela mudou um pouquinho, por isso ele não está encontrando o controller, recomendo a leitura deste [link](http://blog.mnweb.com.br/posts/visualizar/id/490), aqui tem a estrutura que o zend 3 está usando.

Na sua pergunta você apontou esta estrutura de diretórios:

```
-Album
   -config
       -module.config.php
   -src
       -Controller
           -AlbumController.php
       -Module.php
   -view
       -album
           -album
               -index.phtml
       -error
       -layout
```

Porém seu projeto estava com essa:

```
 -Album
       -config
           -module.config.php
       -src
           -Album
               -Controller
                   -AlbumController.php
       -view
           -album
               -album
                   -index.phtml
           -error
           -layout
       -Module.php
```

As diferenças ali em cima são, no ZF3 não existe mais o diretório com o nome do módulo dentro de SRC, sendo assim colocamos diretamente os diretórios Controller, Factory etc. dentro de src. Outra diferença a ser observada é a localização do arquivo Module.php, que precisa estar dentro precisa estar dentro do diretório src no ZF3.

Outro detalhe que notei também foi na sua indexAction(), o retorno de uma action no zend deve sempre (Pelo menos até onde eu saiba... rs) ser uma instância de Zend\View\Model\ViewModel ou Zend\View\Model\JsonModel.

Para finalizar, seu Module.php precisou também de um ajuste no método getConfig, para refletir a alteração do diretório.

Agora ele precisa ser assim:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}
```

E seu arquivo module.config.php também vai gerar um erro na renderização da view, pois ele está com o caminho do diretório errado:

O seu está assim:

```
'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/view',
        ],
    ],
```

e precisaria estar assim:

```
'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```

Pois o diretório view é um diretório irmão do config, ou seja, ele está soba mesma hierarquia, sendo assim a constante **DIR** retornará a localização do config, você tem que subir um nível na hierarquia para conseguir acessar o diretório view.

Com essas últimas alterações que mencionei acima, seu projeto funcionou aqui, veja se consegue rodar ele por ai.

Abraços!
[image: Projeto Funcionando corretamente]

Comment: Já coloquei! Mas não está funcionando mesmo assim.

Comment: Rodou o composer dump-autoload no terminal também?
Aliás, é preciso rodar ele dentro da pasta do projeto, onde está o composer.json
Outro detalhe, seu cache está ativado? Se sim, tente limpar o diretório data/cache

Comment: Rodei, apareceu "Generating autoload files". Também tentei limpar o cache. Ainda não funciona.

Comment: OK, vou tentar simular aqui no meu ambiente... Estou copiando todas as classes que você postou para averiguar

Comment: Bom... vamos lá, aqui nas minhas simulações funcionou, duas observações aqui, primeira no arquivo modules.config.php, inclua antes dos controllers isto: \Album\, ou seja, namespace completo (\Album\Controller\AlbumController::class), segunda observação, no seu controller você está retornando o ViewModelcomo se fosse uma função, e o zend exige que este retorno seja uma instância da classe ViewModel, ou seja, faltou a palavra reservada new antes, ficaria assim: return new ViewModel(); - Vou complementar minha resposta com estes itens ;-)

Comment: Cara, arqui continua com o problema. Deletei o modulo e refiz tudo novamente, e ainda não funcionou. O que mais que pode ser. Ele da como se fosse um erro de route, por não encontrar a página.

Comment: Tem como colocar esse projeto no git ou gist pra gente ver? Por que aqui eu copiei exatamente a mesma estrutura de pastas que você, salvei com os mesmos nomes, copiei os seus códigos fonte... rs Deve ter algo no meio do caminho embolando o meio de campo

Comment: https://github.com/jonathandetoni/teste

Comment: Bom... editei a resposta com mais alguns apontamentos que fiz no seu fonte... rs

Comment: Eu subi com os testes que eu estava tentando, porem, fiz as correções e commitei novamente, e ainda sim não foi. Vou desistir desse framework e migrar para laravel

Comment: Este é o erro que ele me da: The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66941/discussion-between-rodrigo-teixeira-andreotti-and-jonathan-de-toni).